# New to PDO struggling getting the id of my result into a variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

My problem is im querying to get the id from the row on a login request and set $_SESSION name to the id of that row, but im unsure on how to fetch that properly as my usual method doesn't seem to be working.

So im trying ..

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && ($_POST['password'])) {
$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$username = strtolower($username);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);
$password= hash('sha256', $password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `1_users` WHERE username=? AND password=? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->bindValue(1, $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->rowCount();
if ($row) {
// Match
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$_SESSION['user'] = $result['id'];
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = TRUE;
$_SESSION['ip'] = hash('sha1', "{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}");
echo $result['id'];
//header ("location: staff.php");
}
```

unfortunatly `$result['id']` is erroring as a undefinded index..
and `echo $result['id'];` is not outputting anything. but I know the row was found so what am I doing wrong when trying to get the id of that row into a variable?

Comment: Change this `$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` to this `$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`.

Comment: This worked! I knew it had to be something trivial, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `fetchAll()` returns an array of rows (even if there is only one) that are themselves an array of columns, so you need:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $result[0]['id'];
```

Or as mentioned in the comments use `fetch()`:

```
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Which returns one row as an array of columns, then this will work:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $result['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['password']) {
    $username = trim($_POST['username']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    $password = hash('sha256', $password);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM 1_users WHERE username=? AND password=?");
    $stmt->execute([$username,$password]);
    $id = $stmt->fetchColumn(); // <-- here you go
    if ($id) {
        $_SESSION['user'] = $id;
        $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        header ("location: staff.php");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there advantages to ` $stmt->execute([$username,$password]);` and not binding the value sepatly? wont those values not be bound to be a string?